Sorting by multiple keys
I have the below code with SheetName = "SS Colors", and First, Second, Third,... equal to a string representation of ranges such as First ="a5:a174", Second = "B5:B174",...
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Sort.SortFields.Clear
If IsNumeric(Right(First, 1)) Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
            First), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
            xlSortNormal
    Else
        MsgBox ("You must select sort criteria")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If IsNumeric(Right(Second, 1)) Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
            Second), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
            xlSortNormal
    End If
    If IsNumeric(Right(Third, 1)) Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
            Third), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
            xlSortNormal
    End If
    If IsNumeric(Right(Fourth, 1)) Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
            Fourth), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
            xlSortNormal
    End If
    If IsNumeric(Right(Fifth, 1)) Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
            Fifth), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
            xlSortNormal
    End If
    If IsNumeric(Right(Sixth, 1)) Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
            Sixth), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
            xlSortNormal
    End If
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Sort
        .SetRange Range(DataRange)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With

When it tries to execute the first "if" statement with the .sortfields.Add, it gives me a

Run-time error 1004:
Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.

I am trying to evaluate each sort range to determine if one has been set (First, Second, Third...) and add the sort criteria if they do exist.
Any guidance would be appreciated.

All your Ranges need to have the worksheet. Worksheets(SheetName).Range

If IsNumeric(Right(First, 1)) Then  - what is this testing for?  Just to see if it's a range reference?  What else might it be?

It is possible that the user only chooses one of the six possible sort criteria.  So, that if statement was supposed to determine the last specified sort criteria.

I tried incorporating Warcupine's suggestion into my original code and got the error Unable to get the Sort property of the Range class.  I then tried to copy Tim's code directly and got the error Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.    Am I confusing worksheet ranges with sort ranges?  If so, how does one know the difference between them?

Your code can be shortened (incorporating Warcupine's comment):
Sub Sorter()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, ref, firstRef As Boolean, DataRange
    Dim First, Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth, Sixth
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)
    DataRange = "A1:K23"
    '...
    '...
    
    First = "A2"
    Second = "B2"
    Third = "C2"
    
    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        firstRef = True 'flag for checking if the first range is being checked...
        'loop over the range references
        For Each ref In Array(First, Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth, Sixth)
            If IsNumeric(Right(ref, 1)) Then
                .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range(ref), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                    Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            Else
                If firstRef Then 'at least one sort criteria is needed
                    MsgBox "You must select sort criteria"
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
            firstRef = False 'unset flag
        Next ref
        
        .SetRange ws.Range(DataRange)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub

Tested and working for me.  If you're having problem getting this to run, you'll need to provide a little more detail on exactly how you're running your code.

First I tried Warcupine's suggestion in my existing code.  That gave me the error 'Unable to get the Sort property fo the Range class'

Edited above  - code as posted works for me...
